# Select AD member properties + extra column

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm getting AD members for a group and list certain properties from that group. I can't seem to get the group name using the following code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$strIdentity = "TestGroup"
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $strIdentity -Recursive 
$GroupMembers | select $strIdentity, Name, ObjectClass | sort name | Format-Table
```

When I get the output, I get a `{}` instead of `TestGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose `$strIdentity` in double quotes:

```
$GroupMembers | select "$strIdentity",Name, ObjectClass ...
```

If the above doesn't work, try using a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$GroupMembers | select @{Name='GroupName';Expression={$strIdentity}},Name, ObjectClass ...
```

Comment: I'm not following you, can you share sample output?

Comment: Sample-output: {} Smith, John  User; Desired-output: TestGroup Smith,John User

Answer (score 1):

`Select-Object` is for selecting properties of an object so selecting `$strIdentity` doesn't make any sense here. Omit that part from your Select statement.

But what I think you are trying to do is add a property to reflect the parent group name.

```
$groupmembers | select @{Name="Group";Expression={$strIdentity}}, Name, ObjectClass
```

Remember it is all about the objects not text.