# How to get current date in the Get-ADComputer?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

Can anyone help me how to get a `Get-Date` or current date when put after the column `"WhenCreated"`?

```
Get-ADComputer <servername> -Properties * -Server "domain.com" | Select ObjectGUID,Name,CanonicalName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated | Export-CSV "E:\Data\Scripts\Computer2.csv"
```

My expectation to come out the result like below.

```
ObjectGUID,Name,CanonicalName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated,CurrentDate
```

I'm trying to put like this:

```
$Date = Get-Date
Get-ADComputer <servername> -Properties * -Server "domain.com" |
    Select ObjectGUID,Name,CanonicalName,PasswordLastSet,WhenCreated,$Date |
    Export-Csv "E:\Data\Scripts\Computer2.csv"
```

Still got an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select AD member properties + extra column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127410/select-ad-member-properties-extra-column)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use Get-WmiObject method instead of Get-Date, because PowerShell converts the info received into the time of the localhost.

To do that, you will have to store the remote wmi object in variable (target computer) so you can actually use it, then get the LocalDateTime property from the WMI object you've set and converts it `(- $Win32OSVar.ConvertToDateTime($Win32OSVar.LocalDateTime))`, then make the time differences (if you need - just substract the 2 vars).

The WmiObject for that purpose is .CurrentTimeZone

Exemple: `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).CurrentTimeZone`

Comment: That doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: How not ? Get-Date will not work and Get-WmiObject will have to be used instead. What's unclear ?

Comment: I fail to see why `Get-Date` would magically not produce the current date.

Comment: It does, but remotely it cannot be used since that info is converted, as I initially explained. So it works fine locally only. This anyway should be considered a bug and officially patched.

Comment: Where exactly did the OP say anything about getting a remote date? He wants to add a column with the current date. Period.